# Using Javascript to remove url after redirecct

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I have a chrome extension that redirects the (horrible) chrome new tab page to one of the user's choosing (in my case, a html file stored locally)

It works fine BUT it leaves the url "file:///C:/Users/Daniel/whatever/index.htm" in the address bar, which gets a bit annoying cause you have to select/delete the address manually before you can type a new one. Is there any way to auto-delete it when the page has been redirected? Or perhaps redirect without inserting the url into address bar in the first place?

I'm sure this is all really simple and I'm just being an idiot but I'd really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Nope you cannot change the URL without changing location

Comment: Couldn't I make it auto-delete the URL though, after it's loaded?

Comment: No deleteing the url will only change the location

Comment: what you could do is fetch the page with ajax and output the contents onto a chrome extension page